# PlayOnLinux wine error when run NFSU

Tags: 11.04, wine, playonlinux

I installed NFS underground with play on linux.At the program's main page there is a label "Need For Speed Underground" which is selected.I click run and wait.Nothing happens.Then i run on terminal:

```
/usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "Need For Speed Underground"
```

but i get the message:

wine: cannot find ''

What is wrong?

Comment: isn't there a shortcut on the desktop or a shortcut in the ubuntu menu

Comment: yes there is,but nothing happens as well.I just hear the disk spinning thats all.I click properties and found that what it does is executing that command. :(

Comment: i reinstalled the game and got that message while in disk 2 : cannot find required DLL : Z\media\Autorun.GUI DLL

Comment: How about running it with root permissions.do you have windows installed?

Comment: i updated my post and typed the error.I dont have windows installed.I will try now as root.

Comment: i get from playonlinux an error saying that the program i want to run isnt installed...weird :(

Comment: one question, is wine installed?

Comment: yes, version 1.3.31

Comment: i didnt copy anything at all.How can i "crack" it or do what you suggest?The game is original with serial codes etc.

Comment: hav you tried installing it via wine, instead of Play On Linux?

Comment: i tried in the past but i have problems with the second CD.when i mount it wine recognizes the first CD,and now i cant even mark the CD's exe files as executables.I just tried installing missing DLL components via winetricks to see if it can fix anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. Here's a link to the script:
http://www.playonlinux.com/repository/?script=396

Looks like wine1.3 is available here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/wine/files/Source/wine-1.3.11.tar.bz2/download

Something you can do is run playonlinux from the command line, and maybe you can see an error (or where the error occurs) there.

When I was having problems before, it's because the POL site wasn't responding for a few days.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you, using of Virtual Box instead of wine. 
In my opinion, that is most harmonized with Ubuntu or Linux generally rather than Wine.

Up to you, this just an opinion. 
Good-Lock

Comment: thank you for your answer but it's been a long time since i gave up trying to install that game.

Comment: OK, your welcome. Just yesterday I found your question. Anyway, I hope you are well.